# Understand for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import java.lang.Math;


    public class HelloWorld
    {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       int n;
        for(n=1;n<=5;n++)
          System.out.println(mystery(n));
      }
      public static int mystery(int k)
      {
        int x,y;
        y=k;
        for(x=1;x<=(k-1);x++)
          y=y*(k-x);
        return y;
      }

    }
```

This code gives output 1,2,6,24,120. I can understand all except the 1, how it shows 1 in start where for x=1, k=1 and y=1 the expression  y=y*(k-x) will become zero first time. Kindly explain me the output.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @4castle see the question know, i am just asking why this loop showing 1 in output. How can it print 1?

Comment: `mystery(1) == 1`. If you follow the function line by line, that's what it outputs. The `for` loop never runs when `k-1` is less than `1`.

Comment: @4castle according to me it should start from 2, this is the confusion :(

Comment: Can you please explain/show how you arrive at that answer?

Comment: @4castle see, first time the loop wont work for n=1 because when n=1, y will also be 1, so y=y*(k-x) will be zero for x=1, when n=2 how can the expression can print 1 when y=y*(k-x) will be y=2*(2-1) for x=1

Comment: `y=y*(k-x);` only runs if `x<=(k-1)`. When `x=1` and `k=1`, the loop condition is `false` so the loop never even runs, and `y` remains at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the line: `return y;`

This loop does not run when k=1:

```
for(x=1;x<=(k-1);x++)
      y=y*(k-x);
```

So the method just returns y which is still 1 since it was not modified by the loop.

Answer (score -1):

you have for(x=1;x<=(k-1);x++) in your mystery method, when x=1, k=1, this for(x=1;x<=(k-1);x++) loop will not run, because 1<=0 is false! 
The output starts with 1 because it is actually when n=2, the for-loop inside mystery will run for only once (2<=1 gives u false when x increase to 2) and returns the value y=1.

Comment: when n=2, k will be 2 and y=2. If x=1 in below loop, The expression y=y*(k-x) will be 2 not 1.